# How to filter a collection based on a slice of string

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a document in MongoDB with a string type field called `provider`.

How can I construct a bson filter to return all the documents that have `provider` match a string in a provided slice?

I have tried the following, but doesn't seem to work

```
    {
        "provider", bson.D{
            {
                "$in", bson.A{providers},
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: What have you tried (post your code, aim for a [mcve])? What problems do you have?

Comment: Hey @jim did the solution provided below work?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `bson.A` around `providers`

```
{
    "$in", providers,
},
```

The reason the bson.A around providers doesn't work is because it creates another array from iterating over all the elements inside providers:

```
providers := []string{"google", "yahoo"}
fmt.Println(bson.A{providers}) // [["google yahoo"]]
```